# Add class in drop area (file input) when dragging an external image over

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

Hi how to add class using Jquery when I'm dragging element over drop area.

This is my HTML

```
<div class="upload">
   <form action="">
      <input class="uploadfile" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader">
      <div class="circle"><i class="flaticon-arrows-1"></i></div>
      <div class="text">Drag and Drop or browse from you computer</div>
   </form>
</div>
```

I want to add class in upload div class something like this

```
<div class="upload dragging"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with javascript by "listen" to event [`dragover`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/dragover)

```js
var upload = document.querySelector('.upload');

upload.addEventListener("dragover", function( event ) {
  this.classList.add('dragging');
}, false);

upload.addEventListener("drop", function( event ) {
  this.classList.remove('dragging');
}, false);
```

```css
.dragging {
  border:1px solid green;  
}
```

```html
<div class="upload">
  <form action="">
    <input class="uploadfile" type="file" id="imageLoader" name="imageLoader">
    <div class="circle"><i class="flaticon-arrows-1"></i></div>
    <div class="text">Drag and Drop or browse from you computer</div>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: It works but only problem is then i drop image the class dragging stays in div

Comment: My pleasure ;) Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

To remove dragging class when you leave drag area you can add this to Mosh Feu code:

```
upload.addEventListener("dragleave", function( event ) {
    this.classList.remove('dragging');
}, false);
```